# What is the status of rosgo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in replacing our Python components with Go for efficiency and also to leverage capabilities such as channels and coroutines.

Is [rosgo](http://wiki.ros.org/rosgo) being actively developed? What are the future plans for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227332/what-is-the-status-of-rosgo?/) by [calvinjcheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/26032/calvinjcheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickcking](https://answers.ros.org/users/28277/nickcking/) on 2017-11-16**:
I'm also trying to find a golang version of ROS. the Go language is designed well nad python is really slow...Thanks for this info.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-10-01**:
There's [a ticket](https://github.com/akio/rosgo/issues/11) where original developer responded and said he's back to the development of rosgo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have examined state of rosgo further and decided at this point, it cannot be used. The key reason is that it does not have a message generator like with roscpp and rospy to generate .msg and .srv files into Go code. This is the same problem as with efforts to use Javascript.

---

Originally posted by [cxcheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/4113/cxcheng/) with karma: 26 on 2016-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-16**:
What about [gengo](https://github.com/akio/gengo) & [rosgo_messages](https://github.com/akio/rosgo_messages)?

**Comment by [cxcheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/4113/cxcheng/) on 2016-05-16**:
I missed rosgo_messages and gengo. I realize it must have been necessary for that to run the demo.
Unfortunately, it seems that not all the files may have been checked in. For example, gen_go.py is referencing a template_tools package that is not found.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-16**:
`template_tools` is a module in the `genmsg` package. See [ros/genmsg](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/eb17f6743174fd1106930612c1bd9321b41773a8/src/genmsg/template_tools.py). It's not `gengo` specific. `gengo` could still have other issues, but `template_tools` is not meant to be part of it.

**Comment by [andreykyz](https://answers.ros.org/users/37626/andreykyz/) on 2018-09-20**:
I don't see the problem generate message by go generate. I think it is more clear then with catkin cmake based system. (Yes I don't like cmake)